# Configuring the layered costmap[SOLVED]

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am a newbie to ROS. I wish to use the existing implementation of layered costmap for one of my projects. I follwed the tutorials mentioned here:

1. Configuring Layered Costmaps
   http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps
2. Creating a New Layer
   http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20New%20Layer

When I try to configure the layers, it happens that always all layers are existing. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong as I do not get any warning or error messages. I followed the same procedure like mentioned in the tutorial, that is, creating the minimal.yaml file and adding plugin specifications one after the other. And then loading the parameters through rosparam in a launch file.

Please advise what could be done in this situation. Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200826/configuring-the-layered-costmap%5Bsolved%5D/) by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-12**:
What do you mean all the layers are existing?

**Comment by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on 2015-01-13**:
I see static_layer, obstacle_layer, footprint_layers. What I wish to do is add my own layers.

**Comment by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on 2015-01-13**:
I followed the tutorials on costmap layaer creation and if I add the plugins in my local_costmap_params.yaml file I can see the new layers added. But now i want to remove all the layers(static_layer, obstacle_layer, footprint_layers) and then add them one after the other.

**Comment by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on 2015-01-13**:
Also, I had one more query regarding the inflation radius. If the change the value of this parameter, I do not see a change in rviz.

**Comment by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on 2015-01-13**:
In the previous version of costmap if I made a change in inflation radius value the red area surrounding the object used to change. Now its not happening. In fact I see layers around each object with three colors and not sure what does these colors signify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the plugins parameter is not defined in the costmap namespace, then the static/obstacle/footprint layers will be automatically created. You should change your launch files so that the plugins parameter is set using the layers you want.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on 2015-01-14**:
Hello,

Thanks a lot for your reply. I figured out I was messing up with the launch and yaml files and so could not change the layers being used. However, its working now.

**Comment by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on 2015-01-14**:
I had one more query though. If I disable the static layer for global costmap, the planner never generates a plan. So what I understand is static_layer has to be published at least? I wish to write my own static_layer where I want to ignore a few objects mapped in the grid map.

**Comment by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on 2015-01-14**:
Is this possible to achieve? What things I need to take care of to make sure my static_layer is consistent with the existing static_layer and I can run the navigation? I will ofcourse dig into the code now to understand the same.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-14**:
If you don't have a static map, you need to manually set the size of the costmap. Also, if the problem is resolved, please mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [NiranjanDeshpande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4353/niranjandeshpande/) on 2015-01-19**:
Ohk.
Thank you for your reply. And sorry for delay in replying to you.